# Faraday's law of electrolysis and equivalent weight

Tags: electrochemistry

I came across this question in an exam:

> The mass of silver ($M(\ce{Ag}) = \pu{108 g mol-1}$) displaced by a
> quantity of electricity which displaces $\pu{5600 mL}$ of $\ce{O2}$ at
> STP will be _____ $\pu{g}$.

I know the calculation procedure for this type of question. My only doubt here is: can we really have one answer? Since a reaction for oxygen is not mentioned here, we cannot definitely say that its equivalent weight will be $32/4$. Oxygen could get converted to an oxide ($n = 4$), peroxide ($n = 2$), or even a superoxide ($n = 1$). So, according to me we could have $3$ possible answers to this problem.

Comment: You are overthinking it.  $\ce{2 H2O -> O2 + 4 H+ + 4 e-}$ //  I see only two options, involving water vapor or not.